# For a normal distributed random variable X what is the distribution of c/X

Tags: random-variable

Assume $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$

For a normal distributed random variable $X,$ what is the distribution of $c/X$?

I had a look at ratio distributions but could not find it.

PS: The issue originally was raised when I asked for the distribution of $1/\hat{E}[Z]$. I know from the CLT that the arithmetic mean $\hat{E}[Z]=1/n \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$ is (tends to be) normally distributed, for "suitably" distributed $Z_i$ and sufficiently big sample sizes

Comment: This seems to be called a [reciprocal normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Reciprocal_normal_distribution), not sure if that helps?

Comment: Thank you a lot! It is obviously true if I think about the delta transformation method. Feel free to post an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: The claim in your last sentence is mistaken. The CLT doesn't tell you that

Comment: @Glen_b thank you for raising a point. I see there is conditions which need to hold true in order for the central limit theorem to indicate that $\hat{E}[Z]=1/n \sum_i Z_i$ follows a normal distribution for big n. But let's say the $Z_i$ are themselves normally distributed, then $\hat{E}[Z]$ is normally distributed (I think other stable distributions would make $\hat{E}[Z]$ distributed like the corresponding distribution). Please let me know your corrections :)

Comment: Unless you start at the normal, it is not actually normal at any $n$. You assert that it is on your post. It approaches the normal in the limit. It doesn't get there at any same size. In many situations  this may not be a big issue practically  as long as we don't assert that it *is* normal.

Comment: Specifically, $\bar{Z}$ is not actually normally distributed if the $Z_i$ aren't.  Approximately, sure in the right circumstances, albeit you don't usually know if you're in them

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! I appreciate your point and will focus on formulating more careful next time! Hints like this help a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be called the [reciprocal normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distribution#Reciprocal_normal_distribution).